# To increase or to mute volume programmatically for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I wanted to know is there any classes or API for accessing the same ? I have seen lots of applications on windows phone store. [click here](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/quick-controls/843d2576-3900-46e0-a4df-83a0440ead63) for sample.

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=431 try this , that is in Windows form , By using that you can get any Idea in Windows phone

Comment: Thanks, but anything in particular for windows phone ?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Phone, you can use [Microsoft Media Foundation APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681688%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). If you want to use the volume APIs in c# you need to make a reference to a C++ project that does it.

IMFMediaEngine::SetVolume method :

```
HRESULT SetVolume(
    [in]  double Volume
);
```

> Volume [in] : The volume level. Volume is expressed as an attenuation level, where 0.0 indicates silence and 1.0 indicates full volume (no attenuation).

I think you can use a [background audio agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) too.

Comment: Thanks, are there any tutorial available for "Microsoft Media Foundation APIs" ?

Comment: Do you search them ? (if this solved your problem, can you marked it as solve ?)

Comment: I am also interested in tutorials regarding this topic.